# CPU performance affect GZIP IIS?

Tags: iis, azure, gzip, iis-8

I have installed Static and dynamic compression for IIS8 and enabled it.

When My CPU performance 100%, My GZIP IIS didn't working, why??

I can clearly see that GZIP is not running in Live HTTP Header.
What am I missing here?

Does IIS stop performing gzip operation if CPU usage is high?

[image]

NotGzip

Answer (score 3):

Set dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage and dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage in web.config
Details here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression